# same application listening for packets from two different ip's

Tags: sockets, udp, port

Can one application handle incoming UDP packets coming from two different ip's? If so, can those two connections use the same port number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's the point of a server in general: multiple clients can connect to the server on the given UDP port and they can all broadcast data on the same channel. The server doesn't need to have a separate socket connection for each client, instead it just broadcasts data via its socket connection to the same channel that the clients broadcast.

UDP is a little like sitting in a room where everybody yells at each other, while TCP is like talking on the phone with multiple people at the same time.